# How get AWT in Eclipse?

Tags: java, awt

I am trying to run an Abstract Window Toolkit in Eclipse ide. But when i try to import a awt package like "import java.awt.Frame;" i get an error saying cannot be resolved. I have Jogl installed. How do i get AWT in eclipse?

Comment: java.awt.Frame is part of the core SDK. If you can't import it in your Eclipse then something is wrong with your install. Install a clean version of Eclipse in another location on your computer and test your code in it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import a jar that includes java.awt.Frame. The only one I can see is rt.jar, which is the RunTime jar (contains most of the core Java packages). You can find it [here!](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/java.awt.Frame)

Comment: which one should i download from this site? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/download-141771.html#sdk

Comment: I just realised you can find the rt.jar in ../Java/jdk<version>/jre/lib/rt.jar. Then you need to add it to your build path. You can do this in Eclipse by selecting Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External JARs... and then browse for it. Once it's added, that annoying red underline should disappear.

Comment: Although i still can't get my awt to show up. Eclipse Just gives me an error.